# Using 'join' to make new table rather than 'create' or 'insert'

Tags: mysql, sql

I am fairly new to SQL so please pardon me if this comes as a naive question.

If I have to create a new table using contents of another table then we usually do

```
CREATE TABLE table1 AS (select <some columns> from table2)
```

Or we can use `insert into` as well.

But I have also seen scenarios where we create table1 by `join` of table1 and table2.

So my question is when do we use `join` instead of `insert` to create a new table? What are the advantages of one approach over another?

Comment: Use `CREATE` to create a table. Use `INSERT` to add rows into an existing table. `JOIN` can be used as part of selecting rows from tables. They're all completely different.

Comment: if the structure of the new table is identical to an existing one or identical to the result of whatever query, you can use `SELECT [your query details here] INTO newTable` INSERT INTO is used to fill an existing table while `SELECT  [...] INTO` wil create a new table.

Comment: @ub_coding I don't think `SELECT INTO table` is supported in MySQL.